# Should i put images into a paragraph or a html list? - HTML

Tags: html, image

Should i put images into a paragraph or a html list? - HTML

Example, should i do it like this?

```
<p><img><img><img></p>
```

Or like this?

```
<ul><li><img><li></li><img><li></li><img></li></ul>
```

Or somehow else?

EDIT: sorry i forgot to tell you for what i use the images. It's a gallery. I just wanted to know which one is the proper way, or are this 2 both the proper way? Thank you.

Comment: The latter is wise if it's a list of images like a gallery. You should provide some more detail though

Comment: Up to you good sir. Stick them in a div, stick them in a table, stick them in a list, stick them in the body, stick them in a link, stick them anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you should use lists or tables to organize your images, depending on how you want to look. You might want to set it up so you have no bullets or borders in your gallery, though.